# Show messages in open form from background task in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, background, message-queue

I have a background task which needs to show values to the open dialog. I read a lot of stuff about this tasks and adapted the tutorials to my needs. But regardless of my attempts, there is no update until the task is finished and the control is back in the from control.

So what I did in the Content-View, I defined it like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var infoText    = InfoTextObject()
```

with type defined like:

```
class InfoTextObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
}
```

For defining this in SwiftUI, I defined that struct, because classes are not allowed:

```
// small view with text message area
public struct InfoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var it: InfoTextObject
    
    public var body: some View {
        TextField("Infos ...", text: $it.text)
            .frame(alignment: .topTrailing)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)
            .disabled(true)
    }
}
```

The body definition for the form looks like this

```
var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading)
        {
...
            InfoView(it: infoText)
        }
```

And finally the function which is called to update the screen with a new message looks like this:

```
// function to display any text in the view
func DisplayMessage(infoTextObject: InfoTextObject, _ text: String = "", debugMode : Bool = false) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        infoTextObject.text = text
    }
}
```

To me this looks very complex for such a simple and usual task. But even than it doesn't update. :-(

Any hints?

Comment: The code in general looks ok, but I suppose that `infoTextObject` in argument and `infoText` being observed are different objects, so you don't see update (if everything else works).

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: "....there is no update until the task is finished...", this is expected. Your `DisplayMessage` will run in the background,
and when it is finished, the results will be made available through the `InfoTextObject`.  This is what you want right? 
If you want to do the update before it is finished, then put `infoTextObject.text = text` before you start the background task.

Comment: Within the task, the message should display infos several times. So it needs to be displayed while the background task is still running. A typical long lasting job problem, isn't it?

Comment: no problem at all in reporting updates during your long process, using the `infoTextObject.text = text`. 
Whenever you feel it is time to update, at specific points in your code for example, just use what you already have.
You may also want to look at using `ProgressView()`.

Comment: I didn't get it. In the long running task I call DisplayMessage() several times. The screen will not be updated. If I remove "DispatchQueue.main.async {}" within that function, it doesn't change behavior. No update. Seems, that only "infoTextObject.text = text" isn't enough to tell SwiftUI to update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is going on, since the code you are showing us is not the code you are using.
Here is an example of the code that updates `txt` in a simulated background process.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var infoText = ""  
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            InfoView(txt: $infoText)
        }
    }
}

struct InfoView: View {
    @Binding var txt: String 
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Infos ...", text: $txt)
            .frame(alignment: .topTrailing)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: false)
            .disabled(true)
        Button(action: { DisplayMessage(infoText: $txt, "new message to display") }){
            Text("Click for background task")
        }
    }

}

// simulating reporting updates during a long background process
func DisplayMessage(infoText: Binding<String>, _ text: String = "", debugMode : Bool = false) {
    infoText.wrappedValue = text
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            infoText.wrappedValue = "processing"
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            infoText.wrappedValue = "getting there"
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
            infoText.wrappedValue = "close to finishing"
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 6) {
            infoText.wrappedValue = "all done"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example works perfect. I have to check my code, where the decisive difference is hidden! Thank you for that example.

Comment: Now my code is adapted and works fine. Thanks a lot. Would give your 2 thumbs up, if I could! :-)

Comment: you can, just click the tick mark so it becomes green.